# Decrypt XML OKTA Saml 2.0

Tags: c#, xml, saml-2.0, okta

I have to implement an SSO, with an Okta system, and it sends me the XML signed and encrypted with a security certificate, which I have been provided and I have it loaded in a project folder.

I read the certificate without problems, but when I try to read the XML and decrypt it, I receive the following message:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The key does not
> exist.

The code I am using is the following

```
XmlNodeList elemData = response.GetElementsByTagName("xenc:CipherValue");
        RutaCertificado = Server.MapPath(RutaFicheros + "okta.cert");
        for (int i = 1; i < elemData.Count; i++)
        {
            Data = elemData[i].InnerXml;               

            byte[] SamlByte = Convert.FromBase64String(Data);

            X509Certificate2 cerDecrypt = new X509Certificate2(RutaCertificado);

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cerDecrypt.PublicKey.Key;

            var fooByte = rsa.Decrypt(SamlByte, false);

            //var mail = X509Decrypt(SamlByte, RutaCertificado, privateKeyText);
        }
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

****************** EDITED ***********************************
This is the XML I receive from IdP

```
    <saml2p:Response Destination="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/BackOffice/Validate"
                 ID="id73607904232296671938710433"
                 IssueInstant="2021-06-25T06:01:02.988Z"
                 Version="2.0"
                 xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
                 >
    <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
                  xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
                  >http://www.okta.com/ex..................</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#id73607904232296671938710433">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <ds:DigestValue>LM4QiOAUqynTr2eF3fxHPEUpMfjlNaBbvKBkHVJvlSg=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>H7sX3pAKDBETEtmcgNuHa90lrkU1+...........................
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDljCCAn6gAwIBAgIGAV1VxVpAMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGLMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEG
                ..........................................
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2p:Status xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <xenc:EncryptedData Id="_d94b006db4db53071df05233193f954b"
                            Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                            xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                            >
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"
                                   xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                   />
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:RetrievalMethod Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#EncryptedKey"
                                    URI="#_9ef4959105c46c31fff0eda0055c2830"
                                    />
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:CipherValue>jWxhen+PSeeSohWQ/XJARF5vjuN4a+.......................</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
        </xenc:EncryptedData>
        <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="_9ef4959105c46c31fff0eda0055c2830"
                           xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                           >
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"
                                   xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                                   >
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"
                                 xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
                                 />
            </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>MIIDLDCCApWgAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ0FADCBsjELMAkGA1UEBhMCZXMxETAPBgNVBA.......
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <xenc:CipherValue>G4EAS......</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:ReferenceList>
                <xenc:DataReference URI="#_d94b006db4db53071df05233193f954b" />
            </xenc:ReferenceList>
        </xenc:EncryptedKey>
    </saml2:EncryptedAssertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Comment: What type of encryption is being used.  The encryption mode should be in the certificate text.  You may need to use a different Net class for reading certificate than X509Certificate2().

Comment: I use RSA encryption. The problem is not the certificate, since I read it, and doing tests I can encrypt and decrypt a string without problems.

Comment: Try using the tracer : https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/Beginner-s-Guide-to-SAML?language=en_US

Comment: I don't have problems reading the answer, which is what the tracer helps me with, but in interpreting it and getting the data encrypted and signed.

Comment: Do you really know where you are failing?  Which step 1 to 8 are you failing?

Comment: The failure is in step 7. I receive the encrypted and encoded XML. The problem is when reading the encrypted and encrypted node.

I edit the question, so that you can see what I have of XML

Comment: Look at the "KEY" tags in the file.   The error says it cannot find the KEY.  Most likely the certificate you have is a different key.  Read the certificate and check key name against the SAML key name.

Comment: The encrypted response  should be decrypted using Private Key.  `RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = cerDecrypt.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;`

Comment: Well, first you need to decrypt Key sent in the assertion, using your private key, and then decrypt encrypted assertion data using key received on the previous step. It was fun experiment for me, as I spent the whole morning trying to do all the same in Java. Had to use opensaml implementation to nail it.